# Create record in MySQL for Google+ login in Android

Tags: android, mysql, google-plus, google-signin

I am creating an application in which a user can either create an account or use his / her existing Google account. The database in question is a MySQL connecting to the application via a PHP API. When not considering the Google+ login feature, handling the user registration and login is straight forward.

This is how my `users` table is created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userEmail` text,
  `userPassword` text,
  `userAPIKey` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
)
```

I have configured the *Sign in with Google* button and can fetch the user information such as the profile, email, etc. My question is, what kind of changes would the database require to handle users who opt for the Google login (*similarly, others such as Facebook, Twitter would be available too*) instead of creating a new account through the app? In preparation for this feature, the table does not force the user to post his email address or his password. Is this the correct way?

I have searched for the past couple of days without any success. Most results show PHP tutorials. Not even a demo MySQL could be found. If any further information is required from me, please let me know.